Not able to type in VS CODE
I am using VS Code for code editing, when i use (cmd + c) copy command i am unable to edit the code anymore. Although it could be fixed by pressing 'i'.
what's the main reason behind it?
i tried uninstalling vim extension but it didnt worked. someone mentioned here to uninstall vim extension.

Reset User Settings
Sometimes user settings can cause unexpected behavior. You can reset them:

Open the Command Palette with Cmd+Shift+P.
Type Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) and press Enter.
Review and clean up any settings related to Vim or keybindings that
might be causing issues.

